# How can I identify the exact OS version of openSuSE machines?

Tags: opensuse

I’ve tried checking what is the exact distribution of my Open SuSE MicroOS machine. In the ‘/usr/lib/os-release’ file the operation system version is:

```
NAME=“openSUSE MicroOS”
VERSION=“20211224”
ID=“opensuse-microos”
ID_LIKE=“suse opensuse opensuse-tumbleweed”
VERSION_ID=“20211224”
PRETTY_NAME=“openSUSE MicroOS”
```

The problem is that the version is “20211224”, which is meaningless to me. I expected the version to be “MicroOS 5.0”, “MicroOS 5.1” or such.

Identifying the correct OS distribution is critical to me for the purpose of filtering out CVEs, because the fixed versions are provided per OS distribution, as can be observed in this CVE page: https://www.suse.com/security/cve/CVE-2021-33909.html

Is there a way to find the precise OS Distribution? Or at least be able to map the provided version “20211224” to the OS Distribution version (such as 5.0)?

Answer (score 0):

On my system it is in /etc/SUSE-brand which for me contains:

```
openSUSE
VERSION = 15.3
```